# files.exclude for Visual Studio Code not working as expected for files ending in .plan and .tfstate

Tags: visual-studio-code

Friends,

I have the following code in files.exclude in User settings which I understand is global unless you want to override in Workspace settings

```
"files.exclude": {
    "**/.terraform/": true,
    "**/.plan": true,
    "**/.tfstate": true
}
```

The above code works perfectly fine, hiding the unwanted .terraform folder but not working as expected for files ending in **.plan** and **.tfstate** or **.tfstate.backup** files.

I want terraform plan and state files to be ignore by Visual Studio Code, how to achieve that?

Please find below snapshot, I am still seeing  **.plan** and **.tfstate** or **.tfstate.backup** files.:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your glob patterns are off. Assuming you want these exclusions to be recursive, I believe you're looking for this:

```
"files.exclude": {
    "**/.terraform/": true,
    "**/*.plan": true,
    "**/*.tfstate*": true,
}
```

Comment: Thank you mate, works like a charm except for terraform it has to be .terraform else it does not work.

Comment: Great. Yes, realized you needed the `.` after my original post and updated.